# How to get id of process from which came signal in Python?

Tags: python, unix, python-3.x, signals

Please see following Python code:

```
def Handler(signum, frame):
    #do something
signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, Handler)
```

Is there a way to get process ID from which signal came from?
Or is there another way to get process ID from which signal came from without blocking main flow of application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot directly. The signal module of Python standard library has no provision for giving access to the Posix `sigaction_t` structure. If you really need that, you will have to build a Python extension in C or C++.

You will find pointers for that in [Extending and Embedding the Python Interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html) - this document should also be available in your Python distribution

Answer (score -2):

`os.getpid()` returns the current process id. So when you send a signal, you can print it out, for example.

```
import signal
import os
import time

def receive_signal(signum, stack):
    print 'Received:', signum

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, receive_signal)
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR2, receive_signal)

print 'My PID is:', os.getpid()
```

Check [this](https://pymotw.com/2/signal/) for more info on signals.

To send pid to the process one may use `Pipe`

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe


def f(conn):
    conn.send([os.getpid()])
    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()
    print parent_conn.recv()   # prints os.getpid()
    p.join()
```

[Exchanging objects between processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes)

Comment: Thanks for the response! But I want identify pid of process which sending signals on receiver side.

Comment: You can use something like `Pipe` then. I will add some code to the answer

Comment: This does not answer the question. Letting the sender additionally send it's ID via a Pipe kind of makes sending a signal obsolete, because in that case you can just monitor the pipe and do not need any additional signal.